# how do I make the ghost effect for hands like oculus in blender

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, shaders, shadows

I am trying to create the ghost effect / toon effect where anything behind the first layer of mesh is ghosted with just the background. how do I make this in blender. here is a link to some example footage and photos of what I am referencing.[enter link description here][1]

google drive link:
[1]: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CQK07VVAxYEbAsni3rpk7pzazW_Z8DzB?usp=sharing

Comment: i am not sure what you mean with ghost effect...but for me it looks like he just uses some lower alpha value with constant color...[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPoEL.gif

Comment: hello, could you please edit your question and show some images of what you mean (also highlight the part you are talking about)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you mean exactly but if you want to recreate these translucent hands you need:

1. model of hand
2. make sure that material of hand is translucent - in material properties check everything related for it to be translucent
3. use black to white gradient mask going from hand to fingers and use it as opacity/alpha input (so it will appear from nothing) Gradients tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ViqfL0LOwUM&t=147s&ab_channel=InfiniteDigital
4. use outline shader as mask to apply other material/color which will give opportunity to see our fingers on top of the hand itself. One of the outline tutorials: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8iRl9vWOWM&ab_channel=HarishLohar

4(2) also you can use modifier on model instead of outline shader mask: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6YreUxnIP6U&ab_channel=FelineEntity

Hope i helped you! Feel free to ask for more details